# Centering ul or li's in a dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, center

I built a dropdown menu using only html and css. I would like to center the dropdown-content to the dropdown menu when it's clicked.

In my code, this would be centering the purple section relative the light blue section. My code - https://jsfiddle.net/92uhs075/

Any suggestions on doing this?

I have tried changing the `<ul> display: table` and then `<li> float: left`, changing the margins around (0 auto) and negative at times, but nothing seems to work for me.

Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: do you mean that you just want the purple below the blue?  Your blue bar is the full length of the screen and your purple is as well so I'm not sure what you mean by centering.

Comment: If you increase the size of the window, you'll see the purple is shorter than the blue. When it's shorter, I'd like the purple to be centered above the blue. Does this make sense? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your ul is absolutely positioned move it to the right 50% and then transform it back left 50%:

```
ul {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much for the solution. I was fiddling around, testing trying things out for so long.

Comment: On second glance, it seems like adding in the code on the ul tag decreases the list items to display only the last three. Is there any way to get all 5 of them to display? I'll check to see if a width or something is holding these back.

Comment: Since the list items are `display: inline-block` you can add `white-space: nowrap;` to the url as well to keep the li contents from wrapping.